# PHP: MYSQL history feature?

Tags: php, mysql

I save user inputs (comments) in these tables.

```
NEWS_COMMENTS
- id
- comment

PRODUCT_COMMENTS
- id
- comment
- product_id
```

I wanted to add a history feature to my website. Like;

```
-Someone commented on XX news.
-Someone commented on YY product.
-Someone commented on ZZ product.
```

You noticed the issue. I don't save timestamps or dates, so I can't be sure which comment comes first. It can be either the news comment or product comment.

Does MySQL has a feature to select last 24 hour inputs? For example,

NEWS_COMMENTS has 3 new entries in last 24 hours.
PRODUCT_COMMENTS has 5 new entries in last 24 hours.

The query should select these 8 entries ordering by their entry date/timestamp.

Can I do this without altering my current pages? Can you provide a query?

Comment: So **do save** timestamps. What's the reason in thinking of the issues that make no sense and have **valid** solutions?

Comment: I don't want to change the structure right now. The answer of Mark Byers solved it. Thank you for your comment though. :)

Comment: and his answer implies modifying the structure

Comment: Only the database side. I just needed to make a new column without tweaking PHP files. Acceptable by me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is add a column with type `timestamp` and the option `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. You probably don't need any other modifications to your code - MySQL will do the magic to ensure that the timestamp is automatically filled in when you insert rows.

- [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Then you can get the rows from the last 24 hours with a simple query:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM yourtable
WHERE yourtimestampcol > NOW() - interval 24 hour
```

Comment: damn you typing faster than me :(

Comment: Thank you, that was what I needed. :) Going to accept it as answer in few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM  table WHERE timeStamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
```

By adding a column with the type `timestamp` and its open `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` this should be what your looking for, obviously changing the table name and timestamp column.

Answer (score 0):

*"Does MySQL has a feature to select last 24 hour inputs?"*

With your current database structure, no. 
Is it possible at all? Yes. You'll **need** to use t[imestamps](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html). The fact that you don't already for new comments signifies you haven't thought through the entire process of what you're trying to achieve.

Essentially you'll need to add a `cooment_timestamp` field (or other name) as a timestamp type to your database and add an `ON UPDATE` clause : `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Then, you can query (`SELECT`) the data you need using the timestamp information.

```
SELECT * FROM  `COMMENT_TABLE` WHERE comment_timetamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
```